# Не находится элемент через xpath

Tags: xpath, python, python-3.x, dom

помогите пожалуйста найти элемент на странице и вывести его

```
import pprint
import requests
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html
import lxml.cssselect
import re

def get_doc(url):
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
    except Exception:
        print('Error open. __', Exception)
    else:
        html = req.text
        doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
        return doc

for url in ['http://www.ebay.com/itm/DW-PDP-Concept-Pearlescent-White-Maple-Drumset-/121271668104?pt=US_Drums&hash=item1c3c5acd88', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/LOT-OF-20-DRUM-SET-TUNING-KEYS-DW-TAMA-PEARL-SABIAN-and-OTHER-UNIQUE-KEYS-/291092068092?pt=US_Drums&hash=item43c67076fc']:
    doc = get_doc(url)
    title = doc.xpath('//h1[@id="itemTitle"]/text()')
    print(title)

    try:
        reviewQuantity = doc.xpath('//div[@id="si-fbMini"]/text()')[0].strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        reviewQuantity = 'None'

    print(reviewQuantity, end='\n\n')
```

проблема в том, что title находится и выводится, а reviewQuantity - нет.

вот вывод:
    ['DW/PDP Concept Pearlescent White Maple Drumset']
    list index out of range
    None

```
['LOT OF 20 DRUM SET TUNING KEYS! DW! TAMA! PEARL! SABIAN! and OTHER UNIQUE KEYS!!']
list index out of range
None
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что элемента с id si-fbMini на странице не существует. Есть si-fb.
Как вы искали елемент на странице и где нашли si-fbMini?

Comment: странно... у меня существует.
http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/a1.png
http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/a2.png

Comment: http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/729574e367ac8df2c7b256a0ef61dab4.png

Вот как это выглядит для меня и, уверен, для вашего парсера тоже.

У вас случайно не стоит какой либо плагин в браузере который меняет внешний вид ebay? Потому что я не смог добиться чтоб он выглядел как у вас на скриншоте.

Comment: нет, плагин изменяющий внешний вид не стоит. но у меня подозрение, что ebay сам решает какую информацию выдавать в зависимости от географического положения.
я, например, простейшим парсером(заголовки никакие не отсылаю) вижу не совсем те цены, которые в браузере. с разметкой, скорее всего, та же история. возможно такое?
...хотя с другой стороны, в моём случае речь не о классе а о id. вряд ли его ebay изменяет

Comment: Да все возможно. Просто у вас интерфейс русский, а я даже не нашел как его русифицировать.

Смотрите нужную инфу по классу .w2b-head , возможно она совпадет в обоих версиях.

Answer (score 1):

видимо, информация о моём руссифицированном браузере отправлялась в заголовках. я попробовал в вышеуказанном скрипте к запросу добавить отправку заголовков(req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)). в результате скрипт нашёл si-fbMini.
заголовки взял из браузера через FF firebug

```
import pprint
import requests
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html
import lxml.cssselect
import re

def get_doc(url):
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cookie': 'npii=bcguid/7c95fc6d1440a5688552de62fdfa50a754f5e43e^tguid/7c95f5fc1440a2a8c375c1b5fffd89eb54f5e43e^; JSESSIONID=9601E9A22203007B7915707CFECA841B; cssg=7c95f5fc1440a2a8c375c1b5fffd89eb; ns1=BAQAAAUR68LGzAAaAANgASVT39OVjNjl8NjAxXjEzOTM2NjAxMzM2NTVeXjFeM3wyfDV8NHw3XjFeMl40XjNeMTJeMTJeMl4xXjFeMF4xXjBeMV42NDQyNDU5MDc1CHmhyM47efUaKUn0Kc+0JoTQVx4*; s=CgAD4ACBTGBLlN2M5NWY1ZmMxNDQwYTJhOGMzNzVjMWI1ZmZmZDg5ZWIBSgAZUxgS5TUzMTZjMTY1LjAuMS4xMS4xNTguOS4wLjEA7gBRUxgS5TMGaHR0cDovL3d3dy5lYmF5LmNvbS9zY2gvaS5odG1sP19zYWNhdD0wJl9ua3c9ZHcrZHJ1bStzZXQmX2Zycz0xI2l0ZW00YWQxMzk3YjY4B9CKOB0*; nonsession=CgAAIABxTPk5lMTM5NDAwMDIyOXgxMjEyNzE2NjgxMDR4MHgyWQDLAAFTFshtMQDKACBcfMLlN2M5NWY1ZmMxNDQwYTJhOGMzNzVjMWI1ZmZmZDg5ZWIBTAAZVPf05TUzMTU3NzE4LjAuMS4xMC4xNTcuMy4wLjIoOgmd; lucky9=2820836; dp1=bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**54f7f4e5^bl/RU56d92865^pbf/%2346000c0000081000200000054f7f4e5^idm/15316d4d2^; ds2=ssts/1394000335749^; ebay=%5Edv%3D53119bec%5Esbf%3D%234000000000c0000100000%5Ecv%3D15555%5Ejs%3D1%5Epsi%3DA43JRAAE*%5E',
        'Host': 'www.ebay.com',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36'
    }

    try:
        req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    except Exception:
        print('Error open. __', Exception)
    else:
        html = req.text
        doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
        return doc, req

for url in ['http://www.ebay.com/itm/DW-PDP-Concept-Pearlescent-White-Maple-Drumset-/121271668104?pt=US_Drums&hash=item1c3c5acd88', 'http://www.ebay.com/itm/LOT-OF-20-DRUM-SET-TUNING-KEYS-DW-TAMA-PEARL-SABIAN-and-OTHER-UNIQUE-KEYS-/291092068092?pt=US_Drums&hash=item43c67076fc']:
    doc, req = get_doc(url)
    print('----------------------')
    pprint.pprint(req.headers)
    title = doc.xpath('//h1[@id="itemTitle"]/text()')
    print(title)

    try:
        reviewQuantity = doc.xpath('//div[@id="si-fbMini"]/text()')[0].strip()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        reviewQuantity = 'None'

    print(reviewQuantity, end='\n\n')
```